# Which directories are copied to the hard drive when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I want to know which directories in the installation ISO are copied to the hard disk when installing Ubuntu.

Comment: "directory"? This will list them all: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html :-) There is not 1 directory on the ISO, there is a complete system on the ISO (squash-fs).

Answer (score 1):

Since we're installing an entire operating system, there are going to be rather a lot of directories copied to the hard drive...

I'll list the main ones here:

```
/bin - Essential user command binaries (for use by all users)
/boot - Static files of the boot loader
/dev - Device files
/etc - Host-specific system configuration
/home - User home directories (optional)
/lib - Essential shared libraries and kernel modules
/media - Mount point for removeable media
/mnt - Mount point for a temporarily mounted filesystem
/opt - Add-on application software packages
/root - Home directory for the root user (optional)
/sbin - System binaries
/srv - Data for services provided by this system
/tmp - Temporary files
/usr - description here
/var - contains variable data files
```

[Source](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.htm)

Comment: There's also /sbin, /usr, /var, /root, /lib64 (in 64 bit systems), /opt... I don't know if I remember everything.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Ubuntu installer (Ubiquity) README](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-installer/ubiquity/trunk/annotate/head:/doc/README) (emphasys mine):

> [...]
>   **The actual installation takes place by copying the read-only part of the live filesystem**.
>   [...]
>   The read-only live filesystem should generally be mounted on /rofs.
>   Alternatively, an image may be present as /cdrom/casper/filesystem.cloop, /cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs, or (for Guadalinex/Metadistros) /cdrom/META/META.squashfs. **Ubuntu currently uses
>   /cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs**.
>   [...]

Mounting the image for Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 32-bit on `/media/user/livedvd`, mounting `/media/user/livedvd/casper/filesystem.squashfs` on `/media/user/squashfs` and running `ls -ld */` in `/media/user/squashfs`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 2955 ago  5 07:22 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  200 ago  5 07:22 boot/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 1198 ago  5 07:19 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 131 root root 3921 ago  5 07:22 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 apr 11  2014 home/
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root  894 ago  5 07:20 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 ago  5 07:12 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 apr 11  2014 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 ago  5 07:12 opt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 apr 11  2014 proc/
drwx------   2 root root   46 ago  5 07:21 root/
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  310 ago  5 07:20 run/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4909 ago  5 07:22 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 ago  5 07:12 srv/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 mar 13  2014 sys/
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root    3 ago  5 07:22 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  186 ago  5 07:12 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  200 ago  5 07:22 var/
```

Doing the same for the 64-bit image:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 2955 ago  5 07:25 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  200 ago  5 07:25 boot/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 1198 ago  5 07:21 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 131 root root 3921 ago  5 07:25 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 apr 11  2014 home/
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root  875 ago  5 07:22 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   43 ago  5 07:13 lib64/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 ago  5 07:12 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 apr 11  2014 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 ago  5 07:12 opt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 apr 11  2014 proc/
drwx------   2 root root   46 ago  5 07:23 root/
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  310 ago  5 07:22 run/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4921 ago  5 07:25 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 ago  5 07:12 srv/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 mar 13  2014 sys/
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root    3 ago  5 07:25 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  174 ago  5 07:12 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  200 ago  5 07:25 var/
```